# Changing url via html button with JS

Tags: javascript, html, django, url, button

I'm trying to have different html buttons that send user's to different sections of their profile (social, news, email, etc.) So I made a simple JS function which I linked into the html. Basically when a user clicks a button, it should append the current URL with a string and then visit that URL. On click, however, nothing happens:

profile.html

```
<head>
  <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="profile.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1 align=center>Welcome to your OmniCloud Profile</h1>
  <h2 align=center>Access your content below</h2>
  <button name='email' onclick='gotoPage("email")'>Email</button> <br/>
  <button name='social' onclick='gotoPage("social")'>Social</button> <br/>
  <button name='news' onclick='gotoPage("news")'>News Feeds</button> <br/>
  <button name='media' onclick='gotoPage("media")'>Media</button> <br/>
</body>
```

And here is the JS script

```
function gotoPage(var url) {
  var newurl = document.write(location.href)
  newurl += url
  window.location.assign(newurl)
}
```

I'm using Django, so if there is a better way to handle this (perhaps using urls.py, feel free to include that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining a variable in the formal parameters of a function, `var` must be omitted. Also, to declare a variable, you should **not** use `document.write(variablevalue)`. Changing the current location can be achieved by setting a new value to the `location.href` property.

```
function gotoPage(url) {
  var newurl = location.href;
  newurl += url;
  window.location.href = newurl;
}
```

I recommend to have a look at **[MDN: JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)**.

Comment: This doesn't seem to send the browser to the new url. Am I including the JS file correctly?

Comment: Check whether the file name is spelled correctly. Servers are often running under Linux, which has a case-sensitive filesystem. Also, your current code has the following result. **Current page**: `http://foo/media`. **Click "news", opening: **, `http://foo/medianews`. This is probably not desired. Instead of using `var newurl = location.href;`, define `var newurl = "http://baseurl/";`

Comment: The current page is http://baseurl/(user id)/ so it should append after the slash. Even so, I should have seen an error when it tried to visit/1social but it doesn't even get that far

Comment: nevermind, had to add dependencies to Staticfiles. All good, thanks for the help!